# Initializer lists in C++11

Tags: c++11, initializer-list

If I want to create a function with accepts a vector or an initializer list, so something like

```
void fun(const vector<int>& v);
void fun(initializer_list<int> v);
```

do I *have* to create 2 separate functions or is there a way I can get away with just creating one?

Edit:

What if I want

```
void fun(const vector<vector<int>>& v);
```

If I pass this function

```
fun({{1, 2}, {3, 4}});
```

I get an error.

Comment: Those functions do different things. One takes an lvalue, the other doesn't.

Comment: I meant to put a const before it. Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void fun(const vector<int>& v)
{
  for (auto x = v.begin(); x != v.end(); ++x) cout << " " << *x;
  cout << endl;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> foo { 4,5,6 };
  fun({1,2,3});
  fun(foo);
}
```

Running it

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp
$ ./a.out 
 1 2 3
 4 5 6
```

Comment: That version add an implicit conversion to vector and a unwanted allocation

Comment: What if I want void fun(const vector<vector<int>>& v); Passing this fun({{1, 2}, {3, 4}}); gives me an error

Answer (score 0):

You should prefer the standard library way with iterators to feed a function with a sequence of value. And add wrapper for easier calls with a vector or initializer list if needed.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <initializer_list>

template <typename it__>
void fun( it__ bgn, it__ end ) {
  while ( bgn != end )
    std::cout << " " << *bgn++;
  std::cout << std::endl;
}

void fun( std::initializer_list<int> seq ) {
  fun( begin(seq), end(seq) );
}
void fun( std::vector<int> const & seq ) {
  fun( begin(seq), end(seq) );
}

int main() {
  std::vector<int> foo { 4,5,6 };
  fun({1,2,3});
  fun(foo);
}
```